# Building a guided tracing scene

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, ipad

I'm trying to figure out an approach to creating a cocos2d scene that would help kiddos learn to draw letters of the alphabet. Right now I am just using Apple’s PaintView demo code and applying an outline mask for each letter such that the child only sees their tracings within the unmasked parts of each letter. But I want to take it a step further.

Here is how I have defined the challenge:
[image]

I have used Cocos2d before and was thinking it should be used for this problem as well.
I need to build 26 of these and was wonder if sprite builder would be a good tool to layout each letter. If so do you have any hints on how to define the stroke paths?